# Spring Webflux - Webclient Request Body with inheritance

Tags: java, spring-boot, inheritance, spring-webflux, project-reactor

currently I'm learning Spring Webflux and I was trying to do a request with the Spring Webclient (Reactor library) to another Spring Webflux reactive API.

My code to do the webclient request looks like this:

```
public Mono<Boolean> addDomainEvent(Mono<DomainEvent> domainEvent) throws WebClientResponseException {
    return webclient.post()
            .uri("/addDomainEvent")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(domainEvent, DomainEvent.class)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(result -> {
                log.debug("Response received: ", result.statusCode().value());
                if (result.statusCode().is4xxClientError() || result.statusCode().is5xxServerError() || HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value() == result.statusCode().value()) {
                    WebClientResponseException webClientResponseException = new WebClientResponseException("Webclient request failed!", result.statusCode().value(), result.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(),
                            result.headers().asHttpHeaders(), null, result.headers().contentType().map(MimeType::getCharset).orElse(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
                    log.error("Webclient has been failed >> " + result.statusCode().value() + ": " + result.statusCode().getReasonPhrase(), webClientResponseException);
                    return Mono.error(webClientResponseException);
                }
                return Mono.just(true);
            })
            .onErrorResume(err -> Mono.error(err));
}
```

The DomainEvent class is an abstract class, which looks like this:

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
        property = "eventType",
        defaultImpl = DomainEventIgnored.class
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = CatalogCreated.class, name = "CatalogCreated" ),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = ProductAdded.class, name ="ProductAdded"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = ProductAdded.class, name ="ProductRemoved"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type( value = ProductAdded.class, name ="ProductUpdated"),
})
public abstract class DomainEvent {

    private final UUID catalogUuid;

    @Getter( NONE )
    @JsonIgnore
    private final Instant when;

    DomainEvent(final UUID catalogUuid, final Instant when) {
        this.catalogUuid=catalogUuid;
        this.when=when;
    }

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", timezone = "UTC")
    @JsonProperty("occurredOn")
    public Instant occurredOn(){
        return when;
    }

    @JsonProperty("eventType")
    public abstract String eventType();
}
```

And a concrete CatalogCreated class, which extends the DomainEvent class:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"eventType", "catalogUuid", "occurredOn", "storeId", "name"})
public class CatalogCreated extends DomainEvent {
    private final Long storeId;
    private final String name;

    public CatalogCreated(
            @JsonProperty("catalogUuid") final UUID catalogUuid,
            @JsonProperty("occurredOn") final Instant when,
            @JsonProperty("storeId") final Long storeId,
            @JsonProperty("name") final String name
    ) {
        super(catalogUuid, when);
        this.storeId=storeId;
        this.name=name;

    }

    @Override
    @JsonIgnore
    public String eventType() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

When doing the above Webclient request with the method `addDomainEvent(Mono<DomainEvent> domainEvent)`, I'm using an instance of CatalogCreated.class as the parameter for the method. However, it seems that the method just inserts the attributes of the DomainEvent class to the request body and NOT the attributes of the DomainEvent+CatalogCreated classes. With other words, the attributes `name` and `storeId` from the class CatalogCreated class are missing in the post request body, the actual request body just contains the attributes `catalogUuid`, `eventType` and `occuredOn` of the domainEvent class.

It seems that the .body() or .body(BodyInserts.fromPublisher() operators don't recognize that the CatalogCreated class is an extended class of DomainEvent (inheritance).

My aim is to write a method that can do a Webclient request with all parameters of the actual concrete class (CatalogCreated) using a Mono (parent/abstract class) as the parameter in the method declaration. How can I do that correctly?

Comment: this looks a lot like a pure serialization issue. Can you reproduce the same problem without Spring WebFlux being involved? If you create a Jackson `ObjectMapper` instance and serialize/deserialize objects with it, does it work as expected? Did you look at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization ?

Comment: I forgot to set getters on the json properties. This thread can be closed :)